# Ruby: Net::HTTP idle timeout?

Tags: ruby, http, persistent

I am using the Ruby standard library to create persistent connect:

```
Net::HTTP.new(host, port)
```

Does ruby close the connection itself after idle for some times?

Answer (score 6):

Yes. The default for MRI Ruby is 60 seconds.

```
http = Net::HTTP.new(host, port)
http.read_timeout # -> 60
```

If you want a connection does not timeout you can set `read_timeout` to `nil`

```
http.read_timeout = nil
```